# SharedPreference not working- can't see why

Tags: android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

so I'm basically trying to set a BG image for activity2 with a button press in activity1.

I am using sharedpreference so the option will always stay.

The thing is, after the button press, I am saving a string to a SharedPreference:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor background = getSharedPreferences("Background", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    if(btn1 == v)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "btn1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        background.putString("selectedBG", "White");
        background.commit();
    }
    if(btn2 == v)
    {
        background.putString("selectedBG", "Black");
        background.commit();
    }
    if(btn3 == v)
    {
        background.putString("selectedBG", "Blue");
        background.commit();
    }
    if(btn4 == v)
    {
        background.putString("selectedBG", "Brown");
        background.commit();
    }

}
```

And then, in the onCreate of activity2:

```
 SharedPreferences background = getSharedPreferences("Background", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String chosenBackground = background.getString("SelectedBg", null);
    Toast.makeText(this,"chosenBackground:" + chosenBackground, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The last Toast, prints out chosenBackground:null, no matter what button I press.
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: You have your key wrong - change the 'S' in `SelectedBg` to lowercase. Better still use constant key values and reference them if they never change.

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences Ids are case sensitive

Change this:

```
String chosenBackground = background.getString("SelectedBg", null);
```

To this:

```
String chosenBackground = background.getString("selectedBG", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String chosenBackground = background.getString("selectedBG", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use defaultSharedPreferences for simply adding and changing data from any point of app:

Put any value example :

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
                .edit()
                .putString(KEY, "value")
                .apply();
```

Get value :

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
                .getString(KEY, "Default value"
```

);